# Firefox still working in memory after being closed

Tags: firefox, performance

I'm about ready to give up on Firefox, because whenever I shut it down, it's still working in the background, and if I leave it up it, then over time it works more and more.  My hard drive is really being worked, and my system is slowing down.

I have the latest version (3.5.3).

Any ideas on why it is not vacating memory when it's done, and clogging things up?

Comment: What's your OS? When I was running XP I found this to be the case, so when I'd exit Firefox, I would get in the habit of force quitting it.

Comment: I'm using XP SP3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mozilla has a [very detailed article](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Firefox+hangs#Hang_at_exit) on troubleshooting hangs in Firefox, for your such issue:

> **Hang at exit**
>
> Sometimes when you close Firefox, it
>   may stop responding and remain in
>   memory, even though no Firefox windows
>   are open. This can prevent Firefox
>   from working properly the next time
>   you open it or you may see a "Close
>   Firefox" dialog box with the message,
>   Firefox is already running, but is not
>   responding. To open a new window, you
>   must first close the existing Firefox
>   process, or restart your system.. You
>   must then end all Firefox processes or
>   restart the computer before you can
>   reopen Firefox. (See [Firefox is
>   already running but is not
>   responding](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Firefox+is+already+running+but+is+not+responding) for other causes and
>   solutions.)
>
> If Firefox processes that remain in
>   memory at exit are a recurring
>   problem, try these solutions:
>
> - A problematic extension can cause the problem, which can be resolved by
>     disabling or uninstalling the
>     extension. For information on
>     diagnosing and fixing problems caused
>     by faulty extensions, see the
>     [Troubleshooting extensions and
>     themes](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Troubleshooting+extensions+and+themes) article.
> - Sometimes Java applets can cause the Firefox process to persist after exit.
>     Try updating Java to the latest
>     version or, if you don't need Java,
>     disable the Java plugin by clearing
>     the "Enable Java" checkbox in Firefox
>     (see [Using the Java plugin with
>     Firefox](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Using+the+Java+plugin+with+Firefox) for details).
>
> Windows:
>
> - Using certain Internet security software is reported to cause the
>     issue on some systems:
>
>   - If you use
>       ZoneAlarm on Windows Vista, uninstall
>       it and use another firewall product
>       (or use the Windows Firewall).
>   - If
>       you use Avast! Antivirus, switch to
>       another antivirus product if you also
>       have ZoneAlarm installed.
>   - If you
>       use Norton 360 2.0, make sure that you
>       have all available Norton updates (for
>       more help, contact [Norton
>       Support](http://www.symantec.com/norton/support/index.jsp)) and that you have
>       followed the instructions in the
>       [Configuring Norton 360](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Configuring+Norton+360) article.
>   - If you have upgraded Comodo
>       Internet Security from a version prior
>       to 3.10, the Comodo Safe Surf
>       component from the previous version
>       can cause Firefox to hang at exit. To
>       resolve the issue, you can uninstall
>       Comodo Safe Surf via Windows Control
>       Panel, as its function is now
>       integrated into the current Comodo
>       application.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'm amazed they haven't fixed this since it's a known problem.  I guess I'll just have to give up on Firefox (which I only use for the ReloadEvery functionality).

Answer (score 2):

What extensions do you have installed? Many times this is actually because of poorly written extensions rather than FF itself.

Try using Firefox Safe Mode and see if the behavior continues. Safe mode for FF starts with no extensions/add-ons enabled.

Comment: I'll give that a shot just to see, though it defeats the purpose of using Firefox, since the only reason I use it is ReloadEvery.

Comment: If it works fine, you can start disabling extensions one at a time until you find the culprit. That's just step 1

Answer (score 0):

Try opening up Windows Task Manager, click on the Processes tab, then watch the Firefox.exe process as you close it.

It may just be that you have several memory hungry extensions *and* lots of tabs open at the same time. In this situation, the Firefox process can hang around for several minutes after the user thinks they have closed it while it cleans up after itself. You should be able to watch the process memory usage slowly decrease in Task Manager.

Hope that helps somewhat.

Comment: Actually, it never leaves memory until I kick it out.

Answer (score 0):

This drove me crazy. The apparent solution is to delete the "parent lock" file in your Firefox profile folder. Make sure Firefox is off, go to start menu search box and type or paste %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles. Click on the file that appears in search results. This opens your profile folder. Scroll down to parent lock and delete it. You can only do this when Firefox is closed.

The other thing that helped was disabling add ons, particularly Ad Blocker and Auto Fill. This is a pain, though, disabling and enabling add ons all the time.

Firefox seems to be great when you first start using it, but over time, it really gets messed up. I seem to have fixed the problem for now, but if it starts up again, I'm defecting to Google Chrome. Too bad, because I'm used to Firefox, and Chrome isn't so user friendly, IMO.